# Can i set the uploaded image as a background image of canvas?

Tags: javascript

I want to set the uploaded image as the canvas background.So, no changes can be made in the background. Even if I use eraser, it should not erase the background_image.

Comment: What is "eraser"?

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/search?biw=1280&bih=617&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=eraser+in+paint&oq=eraser+in+paint&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12436.14655.0.14753.11.9.1.0.0.0.250.922.2-4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.5.929...0j0i67k1j0i10k1j0i24k1.Hp2RtRqmBXE#imgrc=hFcR0Sk4Gw2msM:

Comment: you can check the link, you will know what i am talking about.

Comment: How is link relevant to `<canvas>` element?

Comment: When i upload an image to the canvas, i have to draw on it, but when i have to erase the drawing, it erases the background also.

Comment: That still does not describe how link is related to `<canvas>` element?

Comment: The uploaded image is on the canvas.

Comment: You still have not established relevance to the link you posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627906/can-i-set-the-uploaded-image-as-a-background-image-of-canvas?noredirect=1#comment78215523_45627906

Comment: I want to set the uploaded image as a background_image of canvas. But on canvas, drawimage() function is used, due to which it allows the user to edit the image. I dont want the user to make any changes in the uploaded image. I just want to write on it.

Comment: Why does user need to interact with `<canvas>` if the user uploads image file to your application?

Comment: Because the image is uploaded on <canvas>. The further editing is to be done on canvas.

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Are you trying to set the `background-image` of an element?

Comment: yes, i want to set the uploaded image as a background_image of <canvas> element

Comment: What issue are you having setting `background-image` at `<canvas>` element?

Comment: I want code of how can i set the uploaded image as background_image of canvas

Comment: _"I want code"_ is not a question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You can use approach at Answer to set `background-image` to uploaded `File` object at `change` event handler of `<input type="file">` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set an uploaded image file to `<canvas>` `background-image` value you can pass the uploaded `File` object to `URL.createObjectURL()`, then pass the resulting `Blob URL` to CSS `url()` function set at `background-image` property value.

Comment: @ShizaArshad You have not provided any code to verify that you attempted to resolve own inquiry. Neither at original Question nor following reading links posted at previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627906/can-i-set-the-uploaded-image-as-a-background-image-of-canvas/45628860?noredirect=1#comment78217065_45627906. You should be able to use descriptions at Answer and previous comment, that is relevant to `change` event handler and `<input type="file">`, to compose the corresponding code to meet your own requirement.